# Swift Confused what this code is doing

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, nsnotificationcenter

currently working on my first swift project and am confused by the following code, i will annotate it line by line to show what i do understand, but on a whole I'm feeling bit confused.

So it is using a notification to trigger, based off a value from the IAP helper class.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MasterViewController.handlePurchaseNotification(_:)),
name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelper.IAPHelperPurchaseNotification),object: nil
```

So this is the method that is mentioned in the above nsnotification. Now my first question is, is this automatically called when the ns notification is received?. The second line i think defines product ID as a variable that can not be changed, and guard sets it to a certain type. Ie in this case it must be a string.
The 2 lines I'm confused about, would have thought it was a for loop, but can't see it iterating so not sure what this is doing. Im assuming the last line is an action when it meets the checks.

```
func handlePurchaseNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
guard let productID = notification.object as? String else { return }

for (index, product) in products.enumerated() {
  guard product.productIdentifier == productID else { continue }

  tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)
}
```

Thanks all for the help, any explanations appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this automatically called when the ns notification is received?

Yes, that's the whole point of [`addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver)

I've commented the code:

```
func handlePurchaseNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
// convert notification.object to string if you can, and call it productID. Otherwise return
guard let productID = notification.object as? String else { return }

// products.enumerated() would yield something like
// [(0, productA), (1, productB), (2, productC)]
// This array is iterated, with the index and product being set to the values from each tuple in turn

for (index, product) in products.enumerated() {
// check if the current product's productIdentifier is == to productID, otherwise keep searching
  guard product.productIdentifier == productID else { continue }

// if we get to here, it's implied the productIdentifier == productID

// reload the row with the corresponding index
  tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .fade)
}
```

That last line is a little silly. [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) takes an `Array<IndexPath>` as an argument. In this code, a new array is made on every iteration, containing only a single element generated from that iteration. It would be much more efficient to produce an array containing all `IndexPath` instances, and then calling [`reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) just once at the end.

Here's my take on this method, which I think is much easier to follow along:

```
func handlePurchaseNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let desiredID = notification.object as? String else { return }

    let staleRows = products.enumerated() // convert an array of products into an array tuples of indices and products
        .filter{ _, product in product.ID == desiredID } // filter to keep only products with the desired ID
        .map{ index, _ in IndexPath(row: index, section: 0) } // create an array of IndexPath instances from the indexes

    tableView.reloadRows(at: staleRows, with: .fade)
}
```